# Refactoring a nested loop

Tags: java, loops

I have the following code which I use a lot of times in the class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < someList.size(); j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            someList.get(i).sendMessageTo(someList.get(j))); //variable action
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the loop is to make each element in the List to send a message (or perform another action) to every element in the list except itself.

Is there any way I can create a helper method so I don't have to repeat the loop code.

Edit:
I need just one helper method to take care of the for loop and the if algorithm. I will supply the List and the whatever action I need to use. It should work for all.

I want to be able to state the variable action and call the helper method.

Thanks.

Comment: A really bad way to do this might be to use enums for another layer of indirection (and I'm not even 100% sure that would work), but I feel there's gotta be a better way...

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like (I don't know what type is in your List, I called it Element):

```
public interface ApplySomeAction
{
    public apply(Element e1, Element e2);
}

...

public void applyActionToAllElements(ApplySomeAction action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < someList.size(); j++) {
           if (i != j) {
               action.apply(someList.get(i), someList.get(j));
           }
       }
    }
}
```

later call it with:

```
applyActionToAllElements(new ApplySomeAction() {
    public apply(Element e1, Element e2)
    {
        e1.sendMessageTo(e2));
    }
};
```

Could make another interface+method with just one element if you often do an action with just one of those elements.

Comment: `do` happens to be a reserved word; usually `apply` is picked instead.

Comment: If you rename that `do` to say `doer` also update the call to `doer.apply(...)`. In Java 8, you can use a closure instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe get rid of one of the loops by doing it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someList.size() - 1; i++) {
    someList.get(i).sendMessageTo(someList.get(i + 1))); //variable action
}
```

And use @NESPowerGlove's solution to abstract the method that's called.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make me an `Iterable`

```
/**
 * Returns all pairs of the list except those where i == j.
 * @param <T> 
 */
public class AllPairs<T> implements Iterable<Pair<T, T>> {
    // The list.
    private final List<T> list;

    public AllPairs(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Pair<T, T>> iterator() {
        return new PairIterator();
    }

    private class PairIterator implements Iterator<Pair<T, T>> {
        // The indexes.
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        // The next to return.
        Pair<T, T> next = null;
        // Easier to read.
        int size = list.size();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            while (next == null && (i < size || j < size)) {
                // Step j.
                j += 1;
                // Wrap j.
                if (j >= size && i < size) {
                    j = 0;
                    i += 1;
                }
                if (i < size && j < size && j != i) {
                    // Grab it.
                    next = new Pair<>(list.get(i), list.get(j));
                }
            }
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Pair<T, T> next() {
            Pair<T, T> it = next;
            next = null;
            return it;
        }
    }

}

/**
 * A simple Pair
 */
public static class Pair<P, Q> {

    public final P p;
    public final Q q;

    public Pair(P p, Q q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3);
    for (Pair<Integer, Integer> p : new AllPairs<>(l)) {
        System.out.println("[" + p.p + "," + p.q + "]");
    }
}
```

Then define an interaction mechanism - this would be almost trivial using Lambdas:

```
// Objects that can interact with each other.
public interface Interacts<T extends Interacts<T>> {

    public void interact(T with);
}

public static <T extends Interacts<T>> void interactAllPairs(List<T> l) {
    // Interact all pairs.
    for (Pair<T, T> p : new AllPairs<>(l)) {
        p.p.interact(p.q);
    }
}
```

Then you can make your message objects interact - here's a simple example:

```
// Interact by sending a message.
public class Messenger implements Interacts<Messenger> {

    private final int me;

    public Messenger(int me) {
        this.me = me;
    }

    @Override
    public void interact(Messenger with) {
        sendMessage(with);
    }

    public void sendMessage(Messenger to) {
        System.out.println(this + "->" + to);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(me);
    }
}
```

Testing now looks like:

```
public void test() {
    // Meassage list.
    List<Messenger> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        messages.add(new Messenger(i));
    }
    interactAllPairs(messages);
}
```

giving your required output:

```
0->1
0->2
0->3
1->0
1->2
1->3
2->0
2->1
2->3
3->0
3->1
3->2
```